# how to make android app density independence?

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, android-support-design, android-multiple-users, screen-density

I am developing photo Editor in android Studio . I have images and icons on my screen which is not fit to other screens(different sizes). I have included following support screen code in my **manifest.xml** file

```
<supports-screens

    android:anyDensity="true"

    android:largeScreens="true"

    android:normalScreens="true"

    android:resizeable="true"

    android:smallScreens="true"

    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

I came to know that density independence is the way to get rid of this. I don't know how to proceed further .please help me what are the steps to make my App density independence? 
activity_main.xml

```
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:orientation="vertical"

android:gravity="center_vertical|center"

android:background="#403E3E">

<LinearLayout

    android:layout_marginTop="30px"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:gravity="center">


    <SeekBar

        android:layout_width="300dp"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_gravity="center"

        android:max="200"

        android:progress="100"

        android:id="@+id/seekBar1" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout

    android:id="@+id/middle_layout3"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:orientation="horizontal"

    android:gravity="center"

    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <ImageView

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_marginLeft="10px"

    android:id="@+id/imageView2"

    android:scaleType="fitCenter"

    android:adjustViewBounds="true"

    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"

    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"

    android:background="#ff0e0e0e" />

<SlidingDrawer

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:content="@+id/content"

    android:handle="@+id/handle"

    android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer"

    android:orientation="horizontal"

    android:alpha="0.5"

    android:layout_gravity="right|top">

    <LinearLayout

        android:id="@+id/content"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"

        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:orientation="vertical"

        android:background="#11111111"

        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:id="@+id/brighticn"

            android:scaleType="fitCenter"

            android:adjustViewBounds="true"

            android:background="@drawable/brighticon"

            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />


        <ImageView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:id="@+id/filtericn"

            android:background="@drawable/filters" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:id="@+id/handle"

        android:background="@drawable/move" />

</SlidingDrawer>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:orientation="horizontal"

    android:gravity="bottom"

    android:layout_gravity="bottom">

<HorizontalScrollView

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:id="@+id/scrollView"

    android:layout_gravity="bottom"

    android:background="#ff030101">


    <LinearLayout

        android:id="@+id/sublayout"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:orientation="horizontal"

        android:background="#ff030101">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonhide"

            android:text="txt"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

To truly be able to have a density independent app, you need to provide your resources in different resolutions. Android is really smart on handling those.

When adding images you should create smaller images, or larger images, based on the format of the screen you want to support and put them in specific folder for that format. Something like this:

- res/

  - drawable/

    - icon.png
    - background.png
  - drawable-hdpi/

    - icon.png
    - background.png

This would make Android use `drawable/icon.png` when you have any other screen density than `hdpi`. But will use `drawable-hdpi/icon.png` for that specific type of screen.

To understand this better, you can read this very detailed guide from the Android docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: You are absolutely correct and this is the problem where i stuck exactly.when i create 9patches using android asset studio,i got hdpi,mdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi,xxxhdpi images.even i use these images my screen is not adaptable to other screens.what should i do further ?

Comment: You need to provide different view files also. Not only images. For each activity that you have you have a .xml file that has the design of that screen. You have to do the same thing you did with images but your view files.